# How to use OrderBy in a data view delegate

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom processing screen that includes a drop down box, provided for the user.  The drop down is used to provide the sort order that is consumed in a data view delegate.  The reason I chose a data view delegate is the query is entirely dependent on the sort order chosen.  Based on the selection, the query must order the results, along with additional logic, then post the resultset to the grid.  I use a switch statement to evaluate the selection chosen in the drop down.  Currently the resultset returns the results of the query.  But the sort order is based on the declared data view.  My order by clause, in the switch statement, is not consumed.  I believe the sort order is based on the keys in the defined data view, by default.  How can I dynamically re-order the result of the query?

```
switch (filter.ProcessOrder)
            {
                //new[] { "O", "P", "R", "B" },
                //new[] { "By Order Date", "By Order Priority", "By Request Date", "By Backorder Only" }

                case "O":
                foreach (PXResult<SOOrder, SOOrderShipment> res in PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>, And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderType>>>>,
                    Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, IsNull, And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<OrderTypes.salesOrder>>>,
                    OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderDate>>>.Select(this))
                    {
                        SOOrder order = (SOOrder)res;
                        SOOrderShipment oShip = (SOOrderShipment)res;
                        //ASSIGN VALUES OR EXCLUDE FRON RESULTSET BASED ON CRITERIA TO BE DEFINED
                        yield return new PXResult<SOOrder, SOOrderShipment>(order, oShip);
                    }
                    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The results list returned by the view delegate is always sorted according to the conditions specified in the view's select. As you have guessed correctly, if you don't specify any sorting conditions in the select, the results will be sorted by keys.

There is however a default approach to overcome this. You may alter the desired sorting conditions for the view using the `OrderByNew` method of `PXSelectBase` or `PXView` in your delegate like this:

```
public PXSelect<SOOrder> Orders;

public virtual IEnumerable orders()
{

    switch(filter.ProcessOrder)
    {
        case "O": // by Order Date
            foreach (PXResult<SOOrder, SOOrderShipment> res in PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>, And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderType>>>>,
                Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, IsNull, And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<OrderTypes.salesOrder>>>,
                OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderDate>>>.Select(this))
            {
                SOOrder order = (SOOrder)res;
                SOOrderShipment oShip = (SOOrderShipment)res;
                //ASSIGN VALUES OR EXCLUDE FRON RESULTSET BASED ON CRITERIA TO BE DEFINED
                yield return new PXResult<SOOrder, SOOrderShipment>(order, oShip);
            }

            // !!!
            Orders.OrderByNew<SOOrder.OrderDate>();
            // !!!

            break;
        // Other cases
    }
}
```

Using the clause like above but with different fields in different `case`s, you may achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case,

What i did was, added a new unbound int column named SortOrder, and i manually sort the result and return it from delegate.

```
#region SortOrder
        public abstract class sortOrder : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected Int32? _SortOrder;
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Int32, "5")]
        [PXInt()]
        public virtual Int32? SortOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return this._SortOrder;
            }
            set
            {
                this._SortOrder = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Declare the view with sorting based on the new column

```
    public PXSelect<Something, 
                 Where<True, Equal<False>>, OrderBy<Asc<Something.sortOrder>>> SomethingElse; // My delegate will give the result always
```

In the delegate, get the result and set the sortorder value of your resultset records and return the result.

and it was working ^^